# How can we create a Java class object and call its method in JSP without scriptlets?

Tags: jsp

Suppose there is a class named as `Demo` which is not a Javabean and has a method `m1()`, I want to call this method `m1()` from my JSP page without using *scriptlets*. How can I do this?

Comment: @russell and balusC, i m asking in scriptlet i can do following-
<% new Demo().m1()  %>

Now my question is how can i do the above opertion without scriptlet in jsp and Demo is not set in any of scope?
For ${demo.m1} demo must be in any of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and do the job in `doGet()` method.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/page"})
public class PageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        new Demo().m1();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

or if it returns some object as result and you need it to be available as `${result}` in EL,

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/page"})
public class PageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Object result = new Demo().m1();
        request.setAttribute("result", result);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

*(note that `page.jsp` is hidden in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent direct access without invoking the servlet first)*

Now invoke http://localhost:8080/context/page instead of http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using a solution based on JSTL and Expression Language:

[A JSTL primer, Part 1: The expression language](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html)

[Expression Language](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

"A primary feature of JSP technology version 2.0 is its support for an expression language (EL). An expression language makes it possible to easily access application data stored in JavaBeans components. For example, the JSP expression language allows a page author to access a bean using simple syntax such as ${name} for a simple variable or ${name.foo.bar} for a nested property. "

This will allow you to use tags instead of scriptlets in the form:

```
<c:out value="${demo.m1}"/>
```

JSTL will also allow you to perform conditions, iterations, and much more through the use of tags.